# Ruby sending xml to server

Tags: ruby, xml, net-http

Im new to network programming and now have a problem with sending some xml data to a server.

I have the following code:

```
require "net/http"
require "net/https"
require "uri"

xml = <<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><data appname="dhl_entwicklerportal" language-code="de" password="Dhl_123!" request="get-status- for-public-user"><data piece-code="034234"></data></data>
XML

uri = URI('https://cig.dhl.de/services/sandbox/rest/sendungsverfolgung')

nhttp = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
nhttp.use_ssl=true
nhttp.verify_mode=OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.basic_auth 'hidden', 'hidden'
response = nhttp.start {|http|
  http.request(request, xml: xml)
}

puts response.body
```

Although i get some response, it is not the right one. For some reason it isn`t sending the body(my xml) properly. If i type the URL manually:

```
https://cig.dhl.de/services/sandbox/rest/sendungsverfolgung?xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><data appname="dhl_entwicklerportal" language-code="de" password="Dhl_123!" request="get-status- for-public-user"><data piece-code="034234"></data></data>
```

it works.

---------------------------EDIT-------------------------------

I edited my code above following the solution from Alex Wayne. Now I get this error:

```
d:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:179:in `send_request_with_body': undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0x29bcff8> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 3):

`HTTP GET` requests cannot have a body, so it the second argument is for data that gets appended to the url as the query string. You probably want to use `POST` which supports a real request body.

```
http.request_post(request, xml)
```

---

**UPDATE:** I think I misunderstood...

According to the query string that works, it's working with `GET`. But it's expecting the XML to be after `?xml=`. So you need to encode you request body/query string as a hash with `xml` as the key and the xml string as the value.

So not this:

```
http.request(request, xml)
# GET http://domain.com/path?<myxml></myxml>
```

But this:

```
http.request(request, xml: xml)
# GET http://domain.com/path?xml=<myxml></myxml>
```

Comment: Thank you, but now i get an error d:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:179:in `send_request_with_body': undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0x298cff8> (NoMethodError).